Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getThickness') from lightning chart JS?
We are using lightning chart JS to plot the graph. When we are updating the version from v3.4.0 to v4.2.1 getting this issue "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getThickness')"
From this error graph is not scrolling from left to right.
using this CDN to plot the graph: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@arction/lcjs@4.0.2/dist/lcjs.iife.js
From the lightning chart migration guide I have implemented some code changes. Not able to scroll the graph.
Documentation: https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/docs/4.2.1/
I want to scroll the graph from left to right without any issue.
